# PHP foreach only in if statement

Tags: php

I have this code that is working:

```
$productID = $_POST['productID'];

$sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_menu_customizations WHERE cust_asoc='$productID'";
$stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
$stmt_product->execute();           
$result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result_product > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
            $menuArr[$row['cust_title']][] = '<li class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap-options"><p>'. $row['cust_desc'] .'<p></li>';
        }
        foreach($menuArr as $menuTitle => $productArr) {
            echo '<div class="item-inmodal-extra"><h3>'. $menuTitle .'</h3><ul class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap">';
            foreach($productArr as $key =>$productname) {
                echo $productname;
            }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Sometimes the query will find results on `$productID` and sometimes no. But I don't know why if the query doesn't find results apache still send me error about the variable `$menuArr`in `foreach` doesn't exist...

shouldn't this variable only be active if the `if` statement is true?

**EDIT**

Final result... better?

```
$productID = $_POST['productID'];

$sql_product = "SELECT * FROM cc_menu_customizations WHERE cust_asoc= ?";
$stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);     

$sql_count="SELECT count(*) FROM cc_menu_customizations WHERE cust_asoc='$productID'";
$countResult = $conn->query($sql_count);

if($countResult->fetchColumn() > 0) {

    $stmt_product->bindParam(':cust_asoc', $productID);
    $stmt_product->execute(array($productID));   
    $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

    while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
        $menuArr[$row['cust_title']][] = '<li class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap-options"><p>'. $row['cust_desc'] .'<p></li>';
    }
    foreach($menuArr as $menuTitle => $productArr) {
        echo '<div class="item-inmodal-extra"><h3>'. $menuTitle .'</h3><ul class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap">';
        foreach($productArr as $key =>$productname) {
            echo $productname;
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}

echo '<div class="item-inmodal-extra">
            <h3>Special Instructions</h3>
            <textarea class="item-inmodal-extra s-intructions" placeholder="Please explicitly state any allergies you have. Requests incurring additional cost are fulfilled at merchant&#39;s discretion"></textarea>
        </div>';
```

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection on the first 2 lines, and learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: check for num of rows instead of `$result_product > 0`

Comment: yeaaahhh it works!!!! rowCount() thanks mate

Comment: You're getting none of the important security benefit of `prepare()/execute()` in PDO. You need to make `$productID` into a bound parameter like `WHERE cust_assoc = :productID` and then pass it to execute as `$stmt_product->execute(array(':productID' => $productID));`

Comment: Well learn is always welcome!!! Done and working

Comment: **From the manual:** *For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(\*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned.*

Comment: well but if I use query() instead prepare() how can I use in the future bindParam() when I need to make a secure query?

Comment: please see edit and let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security issues aside, the answer to your question below.  Your commenters are correct, you should use bound parameters and do all appropriate sanitization but that is another question all together.

Should be:

```
<?php
$productID = $_POST['productID'];

$sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_menu_customizations WHERE cust_asoc='$productID'";

$sql_count="SELECT count(*) FROM cc_menu_customizations WHERE cust_asoc='$productID'";
$countResult = $conn->query($sql_count)

if($countResult->fetchColumn() > 0) {
    $stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
    $stmt_product->execute();           
    $result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
        $menuArr[$row['cust_title']][] = '<li class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap-options"><p>'. $row['cust_desc'] .'<p></li>';
    }

    foreach($menuArr as $menuTitle => $productArr) {
        echo '<div class="item-inmodal-extra"><h3>'. $menuTitle .'</h3><ul class="item-inmodal-extra-wrap">';
        foreach($productArr as $key =>$productname) {
            echo $productname;
        }

        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

[PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: good is working, please check my edit to see if now is more secure